3.3V regulator and Comparator not working as anticipated
This is my first time designing something like this so excuse my inexperience. My objective here is to create a simple circuit for checking if a particular component is good or has been damaged. From my testing so far a damaged component (mic1) will output pretty much whatever the Vdd is, while a working one will output around 1.2V.

I wanted something simple so that the user doesn't need to mess around with power supplies and can easily tell from a LED if the component is good or bad. It runs off the 5V from a USB supply.
Right now I'm having issues with the 3.3V regulator to start. It will take 5.5V and drop it to 4.9V with no load on the regulator. I added a 1k resistor in front of the input and that drops the input voltage at the regulator to 3.9V and the output to 3.66V. I was expecting it to take in 5V and kick out 3.3V but I must be missing something. Do I need to size my resistor differently? I saw a video online talking about hooking up some caps to the input and output and I'm wondering if that's necessary as well?
I'm also not getting the expected behavior out of the comparator. My intention was to have in+ come from the same source as Vdd for mic1 and have in- be the output of mic1. That way when the voltages are the same (signifying a bad part) the output would be Low and the Red LED would illuminate. Then when there is a voltage difference between the in+ and in- (signifying a good part where in- is around 1.2V) the High signal would cause the Green LED would illuminate and the red would turn off.
Could you guys help me out here? What am I missing?
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2903.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1718218489555&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fgeneral%252Fdocs%252Fsuppproductinfo.tsp%253FdistId%253D10%2526gotoUrl%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Flit%252Fgpn%252Flm2903
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2937.pdf
https://mm.digikey.com/Volume0/opasdata/d220001/medias/docus/533/SPH0611LR5H-1.pdf

It's unknown what the circuit really does vs what you anticipate it to do and why you anticipate it. What is the 5V supply, and can you add links to data sheets of the components.

The 5V is just from a USB header from a 5V DC supply. I've added some data sheets for the ICs

Please post a schematic with the tool, that one is not very readable

One thing at a time:
The regulator needs enough load on the output to work properly and regulate the output voltage correctly. It does not matter if you put an extra load resistor on the input, any extra load should be on output. Depending on regulator, it could be 5mA or even more before the output is OK.
The schematics connect the comparator inputs to mic and compare it with the supply. So the mic putput would need to reach and exceed the supply, but it can't, because it can be at less or at most the supply.
And the comparator inputs can't compare voltages so near the positive supply, it works up to about 3.3V-0.7V or 2.6V. So it can't compare the inputs properly.
Also the comparator has open-drain output. It can't push current out to turn on the NPN transistor so the green LED won't light up.
The red LED also won't light up because the PNP transistor is upside down.
To make it work it would need a complete overhaul of circuit and the components used.
